# Hiding columns on a sharepoint table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I am hiding rows of a sharepoint table with thie jquery, but the problem is that everytime the user interacts with the table it's reloaded & the previously hidden columns come back.

```
$j.each(["Type", "Course ID", "Due Date", "Grade"], function(index, value){
    $j(".dxgvHeader_AquaMod", table).each(function(){
        var loopOnce = false;
        if($j("td:first-child", this).text() === value){
            loopOnce = true;
            var index = $(this).index();
            $j(".dxgvFocusedRow_AquaMod>td, dxgvRow_AquaMod>td").each(function(){
                if($j(this).index() === index){
                    $j(this).css("display", "none");
                }
            }); 
            $(this).css("display", "none"); 
        }
    });
    $j(".dxgvTable_AquaMod").css("width", "auto");
    $j(".dxgvTable_AquaMod").css("table-layout", "auto");
});
```

Can you help me get rid of these columns permanently, or re-hide them every time something happens to the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .on() function with a delegate so that all new instances of an element will be hidden.

However, if this is a view, why don't you just remove the columns in the view settings?

BTW, you seem to mean columns, not rows, based on your code.